# postgres - pg_restore error cannot restore from compressed archive (compression not supported in this installation)

Tags: linux, postgresql, rhel

I got below error while restoring the dump file in postgresql 9.6.3 running on RHEL 7.

```
Error - 
pg_restore: [archiver] WARNING: archive is compressed, but this installation does not support compression -- no data will be available
pg_restore: [archiver] cannot restore from compressed archive (compression not supported in this installation)
```

Can anyone please help in this regard ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: > you built *without* zlib support?..

Comment: I rebuilt it with zlib support. Still , the error persists.

Comment: where you able to overcome this